# API Design, Create matrix from variable basis vectors

Tags: c#, linear-algebra

Given two basis vectors, compute a matrix. That is not the question, but it is something I end up doing quite a lot.

Example of such code:

```
var uvec = (currentPos - origin);
if (uvec.LengthSquared() <= float.Epsilon)
    uvec = Vector3.Up;
else
    uvec.Normalize();

var fvec = Forward; // Fixed value

var rvec = Vector3.Cross(fvec, uvec);
if (rvec.LengthSquared() <= float.Epsilon)
    rvec = Vector3.Right;
else
    rvec.Normalize();

fvec = Vector3.Cross(uvec, rvec);
fvec.Normalize();

var mat = Matrix.Identity;
mat.Forward = fvec;
mat.Right = rvec;
mat.Up = uvec;            
mat.Translation = currentPos;
```

What I would like instead is a method like...

```
public static class MatrixEx
{
    public static Matrix CreateFromVectors(...);
}
```

But there are a variety of different cases...

- 3 basis vectors, just need to initialize a matrix with them.
- 2 basis vectors, compute the third.
- 1 basis vector, 1 'approximate' basis vector, compute the 3rd, recompute the 2nd.

So the question is, how would you implement such a method to handle these cases without resorting to a giant nested if/else?

Alternately, if not such a method, what would a 'clean yet efficient' api be? Eg, this api is awkward to use from a client's perspective, NOT because this design breaks abstract code design principle 'foo'.

Comment: [Overload](http://www.dotnetperls.com/overload) `CreateFromVectors` to accept 1, 2 or 3 arguments?

Comment: How would it know if you passed it forward/right or forward/up and do the correct cross-product? CreateFromForwardRight doesn't have a very nice ring to it.